How to list by most used foreign keys in django
I have 2 models: Post and Comment as you can see below
class Post(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField( 
     primary_key = True, 
     default = uuid.uuid4, 
     editable = False)
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField( 
         primary_key = True, 
         default = uuid.uuid4, 
         editable = False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

I want to get the most commented posts last week so how would I list the Posts with most comments.
Thanks!

You can use aggregates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/db/aggregation/

You use an alias and you order:
from datetime import timedelta

from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.timezone import now

Post.objects.filter(date__gte=now() - timedelta(days=7)).alias(
    n_comments=Count('comment')
).order_by('-n_comments')
If you want to fetch the number of comments along with it, you can use  .annotate(…) [Django-doc] over .alias(…) [Django-doc]:
from datetime import timedelta

from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.timezone import now

Post.objects.filter(date__gte=now() - timedelta(days=7)).annotate(
    n_comments=Count('comment')
).order_by('-n_comments')
The Post objects arising from this will have an extra attribute .n_comments, with the number of Comments for that `Post.

Wouldn't .annotate() also do, to borrow the canonical tutorial example?

@AKX: yes, but then you also retrieve it in the SELECT, and because Django doesn't use an "alias", it will thus count even twice, this will typically not mean the query runs two times, because most of the delay is just waiting for storage to retrieve the data, but still produces a lot of extra CPU cycles.

Good point! On a similar note, I've noticed .only() and .defer() also end up in a deoptimized codepath since they can't just splat all attributes directly onto empty model instances.
